# Elasticsearch show text field terms for search query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with field `content`, here is a mapping:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "content": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "english"
        }
    }
}
```

And I have a simple search query

```
curl -X GET 'localhost:9200/idx/_search'  -H 'content-type: application/json' -d '{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "content": "yellow fox"
    }
  },
  "fields": [
    "content"
  ]
}'

{
   ...
   "hits" : {
      "hits" : [
         {
            ...
            "fields" : {
               "content" : [
                  "Yellow foxes jump"
               ]
            },
         }
   ...
}
```

How can I modify my search query to also receive content terms like [analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) provides:

```
curl -X GET  127.0.0.1:9200/_analyze  -H 'content-type: application/json' -d '{ 
    "analyzer" : "english", 
    "text" : "yellow foxes"
}'

{
   "tokens" : [
      {
         "end_offset" : 6,
         "position" : 0,
         "start_offset" : 0,
         "token" : "yellow",
         "type" : "<ALPHANUM>"
      },
      {
         "end_offset" : 12,
         "position" : 1,
         "start_offset" : 7,
         "token" : "fox",
         "type" : "<ALPHANUM>"
      }
   ]
}
```

Generally, desired output of search query look like this

```
{
   ...
   "hits" : {
      "hits" : [
         {
            ...
            "fields" : {
               "content" : [
                  "Yellow foxes jump"
               ],
               "content_terms": [
                 "yellow", "fox", "jump"
               ]
            },
         }
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to do anything special to search terms - as you are already doing it. When you give a sentence inside a match query - the sentence itself is tokenized using the same analyzer it was indexed.

which means, if the query is "quick brown fox" - its searching for "quick" "brown" "fox" ; In case of phrase query - ES also will check if all terms are in proximity.

Comment: I mean I want to receive tokenized field `content` in addition to plain text for search query. Now I run `/_analyze` query for each result from search query.

Comment: Or you can tokenize in indexing time by running same analyzer and storing it in   field with  index=false , it will be part of _source payload then ; No other special tricks AFAIK